# Sum of three probability density functions.

Tags: probability-distributions

If $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ are independent and have pdf $f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ when $t \geq 0$ and $0$ when $t<0$. What is the pdf of the sum $A_1+A_2+A_3$.

So the first step is the  pdf of sum $A_1+A_2$ which is the convolution

\begin{align} 
f(z)&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z-t)f(t) dt \\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{z} \lambda e^{-\lambda z+\lambda t} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt \\
&=\lambda^2 \int\limits_{0}^{z} e^{-\lambda z} dt \\
&=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} \int\limits_{0}^{z} 1 dt \\
&=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} z
\end{align}
when $z \geq 0$ and $0$ when $z<0$.

So isn't the pdf of the sum $A_1+A_2+A_3$ convolution $f(z) \star f(t)$

\begin{align} 
f(\tau)&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau-z)f(z) dz \\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{\tau} \lambda e^{-\lambda\tau+\lambda z}\cdot \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} z \;  dz \\
&=\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda \tau} \int\limits_{0}^{\tau} z \;dz \\
&=\frac{\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda \tau} \tau^2}{2}
\end{align}

Is this correct or are the limits of the integral wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. Another way to do it is to notice that

$P(A_1 + A_2 + A_3  \leq t) = P(X \geq 3)$

where $X$ is a Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda t$, so

$P(A_1 + A_2 + A_3  \leq t) = P(X \geq 3) = 1- e^{-\lambda t} -\lambda t e^{-\lambda t} - \dfrac{\lambda^2 t^2}{2}e^{-\lambda t}$,

Then take derivative with respect to $t$ to refind the same result

Comment: Hmm that is nice observation. But I don't get the same result..Should you get $\frac{\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda \tau} \tau^2}{2}$ if you derivate that ($t=\tau$)?

Comment: @ELEC Yes, I've done the computation, the result is the same

Comment: Okey. I guess I was just too lazy to simplify the result.

Comment: Oh and thank you alot!

Comment: @ELEC You are welcome!